# Sorting data frame by time period; datetime64[ns]

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, date, time

I have another issue with summing up a column
(Python - Pandas)

I have a data frame "new" with Dates from a periods of 5 days.
The 'Dates' column is the type datetime64[ns].
I try to filter the data frame by date, for example "all values between 2021-10-10 and 2021-10-15" or "all values after 2021-10-14" etc.
No matter what I try, I get error messages.
Starting with:

```
mask = (new['Date'] > '2021-10-10') & (df['Date'] <= '2021-10-15')
```

I get:

```
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'date time.date' and 'str'
```

After this error I try to transform the slices, following the advice
"The thing is you want to slice using Strings '2017-07-07' while your index is of type date time.date. Your slices should be of this type too.
You can do this by defining your start date and end date as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
startdate = pd. to_datetime("2017-7-7").date()
enddate = pd. to_datetime("2017-7-10").date()
df.loc[startdate:enddate]
```

(I remove the spaces of course)
But now I get

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'date time.date'
```

I just want to sort and filter my data frame by different time periods.
Thanks for any help

Comment: how is that related to "Summing up decimal numbers"?

Comment: I'm sorry, that was a mistake! I'll change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to ensure everything is in the same format use `pd.to_datetime()` and using `infer_datetime_format=True` helps with the formatting and speeds up the function too:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],infer_datetime_format=True)

df = df[(df['Date'] > pd.to_datetime('2021-10-10')) & (df['Date'] <= pd.to_datetime('2021-10-15'))]
```

Comment: How can I now set the `startdate = pd. to_datetime("2017-7-7").date()` and 
`enddate = pd. to_datetime("2017-7-10").date()`? It gives the error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'date'

Comment: Use .dt.date instead of .date()